# Socket.IO - Android - SSL connection failed

Tags: android, ssl, socket.io

I made a nede & Socket.IO server a web clien, and an android client and it works ! They can communicate !
Cool, so now, I'm trying to make it compatible with SSL.
I'm using "Let's Encrypt - Free SSL/TLS Certificates". My server and my web client are working (Yepee :D)

But my Android client can't connect to the server...

That's my Android code :

```
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
        IO.setDefaultSSLContext(sc);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session){
                return true;
            }
        });
        IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
        opts.forceNew = true;
        opts.reconnection = true;
        opts.secure = true;
        opts.sslContext = sc;

        this.socket = IO.socket(this.SERVER_URL, opts);
```

And that's the error :

```
com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
```

Have you got an idea to solve it ? :D

Comment: Does a scan of your site at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html indicate an incomplete certificate chain or any other certificate related issues?

Comment: Tel me ^^ I think it's ok : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=antoineduval.fr&hideResults=on